# Conditionally Load Angular Library

Tags: modernizr

Trying to load Angular library conditionally using Modernizr, if CDN fails want it to load the library from local machine but it is not working, so what could be the reason

```
Modernizr.load([
        {
            load: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js",
            complete: function () {
                if(!window.angular){
                    Modernizr.load("bower_components/angular/angular.min.js");
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Standart Angular library missing errors

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:37 Uncaught
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=modalApp&p1=Error%3…udflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so like the error says, Modernizr doesn't know what angular is, which means your fallback doesn't work. Take a look at this code:

```
 Modernizr.load([
        {
            load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js',
            complete: function () {
                if (!window.jQuery) {
                    Modernizr.load('js/libs/jquery-1.6.4.min.js');
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // This will wait for the fallback to load and
            // execute if it needs to.
            load: 'needs-jQuery.js'
        }
    ]);
```

This code attempts to load jQuery from the Google CDN first. Once the script is downloaded (or if it fails) the function associated with complete will be called. The function checks to make sure that the jQuery object is available and if it’s not Modernizr is used to load a local jQuery script. After all of that occurs a script named needs-jQuery.js will be loaded. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/detecting-html5-css3-features-using-modernizr

**Edit**

so change this

```
load: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js",
```

to this

```
load: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js,
```

Comment: Ok I am already using this code for my jQuery conditional load, how can I check Angular and load if it is not exist?

Comment: this code works for jQuery but it is not working for Angular and the solution you suggest does not work as well unfortunately.
Probably there is nothing like window.angular. I don't know maybe it is not possible to conditionally load Angular library. Don't know.

Comment: <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
 <script>
 Modernizr.load([
        {
            load: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js',
            complete: function () {
                if (!window.angular) {
                    Modernizr.load('bower_components/angular/angular.min.js');
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
 </script>